# ItemsCarousel React

Tags: reactjs

hello can any one help on this fro itemsCarousel for not scrolling to first item..if tried to see third item, I can see that again first item will appear in the list, that i cant see the third item is active or not....as i am trying to use itemsCarousel for list of menu that i have more than 10 options.
i have developed sample project in the condesandox this is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-meitner-vy00p

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import MenuOne from "./menu-one";
import MenuTwo from "./menu-two";
import MenuThree from "./menu-three";
import MenuFour from "./menu-four";
import MenuFive from "./menu-five";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MenuOne} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-two" component={MenuTwo} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-three" component={MenuThree} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-four" component={MenuFour} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-five" component={MenuFive} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

menu.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ItemsCarousel from "react-items-carousel";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);
  const chevronWidth = 40;
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: `0 ${chevronWidth}px` }}>
      <ItemsCarousel
        requestToChangeActive={setActiveItemIndex}
        activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
        numberOfCards={2}
        gutter={20}
        leftChevron={<button>{"<"}</button>}
        rightChevron={<button>{">"}</button>}
        outsideChevron
        chevronWidth={chevronWidth}
      >
        <NavLink to="/">Menu One</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/menu-two">Menu Two</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/menu-three">Menu Three</NavLink>
      </ItemsCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

menu-one.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./menu";

export default class MenuOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <div>This is Menu One</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

menu-two

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./menu";

export default class MenuTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <div>This is Menu Two</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

menu-three

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./menu";

export default class MenuThree extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <div>This is Menu Three</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** A new menu is rendered on each page (old one unmounted). Each time it displays with initial "state"

**Solution:** Move the "nav" menu out of each component and into the router. This allows it to remain mounted for all page/route transitions.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Menu />
        <Route exact path="/" component={MenuOne} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-two" component={MenuTwo} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-three" component={MenuThree} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-four" component={MenuFour} />
        <Route exact path="/menu-five" component={MenuFive} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Menu.js - provide an `activeClassName` or inline style for the active link

```
<NavLink activeClassName="activeLink" exact to="/"> // <-- specify exact prop here else it will match all routes!
  Menu One
</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName="activeLink" to="/menu-two">
  Menu Two
</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName="activeLink" to="/menu-three">
  Menu Three
</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName="activeLink" to="/menu-four">
  Menu Four
</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName="activeLink" to="/menu-five">
  Menu Five
</NavLink>
```

CSS

```
.activeLink {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: Edit eloquent-banzai-venvj]

Comment: the way of item carousel i have used in different way please see this link of stackover flow question.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343533/items-carousel-for-menu-list-using-react-js