# items carousel for menu list using react js

Tags: reactjs

itemsCarousel for not scrolling to first item..if tried to see third item, I can see that again first item will appear in the list, that i cant see the third item is active or not....as i am trying to use itemsCarousel for list of menu that i have more than 10 options. please go through below link of codesandbox code is availble there https://codesandbox.io/s/still-pine-kl9jb?file=/src/main-menu.js:0-939

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row } from "react-grid-system";
import firstCard from "./menu/firstcard";
import secondCard from "./menu/secondcard";
import thridCard from "./menu/thirdCard";
import fouthCard from "./menu/fourthcard";
import fifthCard from "./menu/fifthcard";

import cardone from "./secondMenu/card-one";
import cardtwo from "./secondMenu/card-two";
import cardthree from "./secondMenu/card-three";
import cardfour from "./secondMenu/card-four";
import cardfive from "./secondMenu/card-five";

import itemone from './thirdMenu/itemOne'
import itemtwo from './thirdMenu/itemTwo'
import itemthree from './thirdMenu/itemThree'
import itemfour from './thirdMenu/itemFour'

import MainMenu from "./main-menu";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={firstCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={secondCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={thridCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={fouthCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={fifthCard} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardone} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardtwo} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardthree} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardfour} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardfive} />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemone} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemtwo} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemthree} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemfour} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

mainmenu.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './styles.css'
import ItemsCarousel from "react-items-carousel";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);
  const chevronWidth = 40;
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: `0 ${chevronWidth}px` }}>
      <ItemsCarousel
        requestToChangeActive={setActiveItemIndex}
        activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
        numberOfCards={2}
        gutter={20}
        leftChevron={<button>{"<"}</button>}
        rightChevron={<button>{">"}</button>}
        outsideChevron
        chevronWidth={chevronWidth}
      >
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="activeclass" to="/">Menu</NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="activeclass" to="/secondmenu">Second Menu</NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="activeclass" to="/thirdmenu">Third Menu</NavLink>
       </ItemsCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow the "table" layout with rows and columns, but moving the "navigation" menu *out* of a route and just rendered into the `Router` resolves the issue of each "page" having a copy and getting reinitialized when it loads. This is why you see it "snap" back to displaying the first menu after scrolling right and clicking on third menu.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
              <MainMenu /> // render outside a route so it is always just there
            {/* <Route exact path="/">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route> */}
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={firstCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={secondCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={thridCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={fouthCard} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={fifthCard} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            {/* <Route exact path="/secondmenu">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route> */}
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardone} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardtwo} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardthree} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardfour} />
            <Route exact path="/secondmenu" component={cardfive} />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            {/* <Route exact path="/thirdmenu">
              <MainMenu />
            </Route> */}
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} xs={12}>
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemone} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemtwo} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemthree} />
            <Route exact path="/thirdmenu" component={itemfour} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```